# How to unit test ActiveRecord scope in a service class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

What is the right way to mock the input to my AR association chain in my class

```
class OfficeHourScheduler 
  def initialize(company)
    @company = company
  end

  def active_office_holiday
    @company.office_holidays.active
  end
end
```

So in my Rspec I want to test the output of active_office_holiday without creating any real data in DB.

Currently Im testing like this, not sure if its the best way.

```
  expect_any_instance_of(Company).to receive_message_chain('office_holidays.active')
```

Comment: I think you can use symbol like this  `expect_any_instance_of(Company).to receive_message_chain(:office_holidays, :active)`

Answer (score 0):

`expect ... to receive` mode does not make sure you can get the correct result, right?

One question is, why you don't want to create data in the db? It's just testing database.

I would create several records in the database. eg. 2 companies A & B, and 2 office_holidays for company A, one is active and one is not active, and 1 office_holiday for company B.

When you pass in company A to your class, I will expect `@company.office_holdays` to return these 2 corresponding records. And after you call `active`, both of these holidays should become active.

Answer (score 0):

In your current test, you're not testing the results of the scope, but just the fact that `office_holidays` and `active` from `Company` are called.

One way you could do this is, for instance :

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe OfficeHourScheduler do
  describe '#active_office_holiday' do
    it 'returns the active holidays of the company' do
      company = FactoryBot.create(:company)
      active_holiday = FactoryBot.create(:office_holiday, company: company, active: true)
      inactive_holiday = FactoryBot.create(:office_holiday, company: company, active: false)

      expect(described_class.new(company).active_office_holiday).to match_array [active_holiday]
    end
  end
end
```